# D3.JS Histogram: error aligning bars when updating data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm attempting to update data in a histogram chart with D3.JS. I'm experiencing a problem when updating the data where the bars no longer align with the x-axis after the data updates.

Here is a link to a live demo:
http://bl.ocks.org/clhenrick/b26a7310edf204f3c209

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

On [line 239](https://gist.github.com/clhenrick/b26a7310edf204f3c209#file-index-html-L239)—

```
bar.append("rect")
```

—you probably meant `.select`, not `.append`.

Your current code is appending a new set of `<rect>`s every time the chart updates, and the old ones aren't aligned right.

[image: before]

Note the increasing size of the d3 selection that I'm running in the dev tools on the right.

When fixed, it looks like this:

[image: after]

Comment: Getting the bars' transitions right is the domain of another question. ;)

Comment: +1 for the animated GIFs! I actually realized that removing the space between `bar.data` and `bar.append` fixed the issue. Somehow calling `bar` twice was creating the error.

Answer (score 1):

Editing lines 232 - 242 in `index.html` so that `bar` was not called twice fixed the problem, as well as changing `.append` to `.select`.

**Previous code:**

```
bar.data(newhistdata)
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
      return "translate(" + x2(i * binsize + minbin) + "," + y(d.numFlips) + ")"; 
    });
bar.append("rect")
  .attr("x", x(binmargin))
  .attr("width", x(binsize - 2 * binmargin))
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.numFlips); });
```

**Edited:**

```
bar.data(newhistdata)
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
      return "translate(" + x2(i * binsize + minbin) + "," + y(d.numFlips) + ")"; 
    })
  .select('rect')
  .attr('x', x(binmargin))
  .attr("width", x(binsize - 2 * binmargin))
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.numFlips); });
```